# hikari pool is throwing timeout

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE, `hikari` version `3.4.1`

Getting following timeout error in `hikari`

> Timeout failure stats (total=30, active=1, idle=29, waiting=163)

There are 29 idle connections, still timeout failure is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below configuation , We had a same issue on our QA environment this config works for 50-100 requests per second , Please leave idle timeout and max lifetime as is

```
private static DataSource pool;
final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setMinimumIdle(5);
config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
config.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
config.setJdbcUrl(JDBC_URL);
config.setUsername(JDBC_USER);
config.setPassword(JDBC_PASS);

pool = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Comment: Ok, i will try. But why is application is not able to get connection from the pool. Although its showing idle connections as 29

Comment: The other issue may be the connection leak and then problem is not related to HikariCP.  Sometimes the problem persisted because of some complex methods executing multiple changes in DB through JPA repositories. For some reasons calls to these interfaces resulted in a growing number of "freezed" active connections, exhausting the pool. Either annotating these methods as @Transactional or enveloping all the logic in a single call to transactional service method should solve the problem.

Comment: But the active connections are not freezed. As the active connection is only one, means connections are getting released. Idle connections ie NOT_IN_USE connections are showing 29 out of total 30 connections. Issue is coming randomly. For 30 minutes application was unable to get connection, then it corrected on its own

Comment: Also its not connection leak, as connections are getting released, its confirmed.